# Character Insertion in Character Array C

Tags: c, arrays, string, character, concatenation

I am trying to insert a special character '-' in the character array and wants to save it in another string. The character to be inserted is done using a loop.

**INPUT:**

actgagc

atgac

**OUTPUT**

actgagc

a-tga-c

In the second character array - is inserted in place of the missing characters.

The program is being done in the JAVA using the simple string concatenation function but unable to do the character insertion for C Language.

The Java Code is:

```
while (k > 0 && l > 0) {
            if (condition 1) {
                r_string1 += string_1[k - 1];
                r_string2 += string_2[l - 1];
                k--;
                l--;
            } else if (condition) {
                r_string1 += "-";
                r_string2 += string_2[l - 1];
                l--;
            } else {
                r_string1 += sring_1[k - 1];
                r_string2 += "-";
                k--;
            }
        }
```

In C language i am trying to do the same for the character insertion in the character array. Tried with the strcat, memmov function but no results are achieved.

Comment: SO is not a human-powered transpiler service. Show us what you've tried in C so far. Right now, you have some Java pseudo-code, but you don't show us what you've tried to acchieve the same thing in C. Read the help section on what makes a _"good question"_

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space for the new string so don't forget to free it...

```
char * f(char *s1, char * s2)
{
    char *s3 = malloc(strlen(s2)+1);
    char *ret = s3;

    while (*s2)
    {
        if (*s1++ == *s2)
            *s3 = *s2++;
        else
            *s3 = '-';
        s3++;
    }
    *s3 = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```